# missing dependencies when running playwright in docker

Tags: docker, dependencies, playwright

I tried to run the playwright in docker but got this error:

```
browserType.launch: Host system is missing dependencies!

Missing libraries are:
  libvpx.so.6
  libicui18n.so.66
  libicuuc.so.66
  libwoff2dec.so.1.0.2
  libharfbuzz-icu.so.0
  libgstgl-1.0.so.0
  libgstcodecparsers-1.0.so.0
  libjpeg.so.8
  libenchant.so.1
  libsecret-1.so.0
  libhyphen.so.0
  libGLESv2.so.2
```

Then I tried to install the necessary libs to make the bundled version of playwright work by adding:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget --no-install-recommends \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
    libvpx6 \
    lib64icui18n66 \
    libicuuc66 \
    ....
```

But I still get these errors:

```
E: Unable to locate package libvpx6 // I tried with libvpx5 but got the same error
E: Unable to locate package lib64icui18n66
E: Unable to locate package libicuuc66
....
```

Docker OS

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.13 (stretch)
Release:        9.13
Codename:       stretch
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Are you using the playwright image?

Comment: @hardkoded I have a node project that runs the playwright and I add all to the docker by commands:
...
WORKDIR /app
ADD . ./
RUN yarn install
...

Comment: There's a new Docker image from Microsoft with playwright installed: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/26482

Answer (score 6):

With modern versions of playwright, you can easily add the necessary packages to any container with the following command:

```bash
npx playwright install-deps
```

This is much better than manually installing them because it will stay in sync with playwright updates.

---

*Note: The previous answer, while technically correct, will bloat your container with a heavy layer that you probably don't need.*

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.6.2-focal
```

The above command should add all those missing dependencies to launch the tests.

Comment: do you know the one for debian 10? thanks.

Comment: It should be the same. could you check this one in Debian ?

Comment: thanks! (switched to ubuntu for other raesons as well)