# Playwright failed in the Gitlab pipeline with browserType.launch: Host system is missing dependencies

Tags: gitlab, pipeline, playwright, cicd

I know my question is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65802328/missing-dependencies-when-running-playwright-in-docker), but hope someone can help me to execute Playwright tests in the Gitlab pipeline.

My .gitlab-ci.yaml insludes next lines:

```
image: node:16.13.0
...
test e2e:
  stage: test
  script:
    - npx playwright install
    - npm run test-e2e
```

Can I somehow set a proper docker image or OS that [is supported](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/3167)..?

[image]

Comment: Not sure, but in majority of cases you will declare a package.json file on the root level of your proj, and declare all dependencies there.

So you will not run npm install playwright, but
npm install

Comment: From the official docs (https://playwright.dev/docs/intro):
`npm i -D @playwright/test
# install supported browsers
npx playwright install`.
Only `@playwright/test` will be added to the package.json and installed with `npm i`.

Answer (score 2):

Was described in the official docs https://playwright.dev/docs/ci#gitlab-ci

You can set image per job like in my case:

```
test e2e:
  stage: test
  **image: mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.16.3-focal**
  script:
   - npx playwright install
   - npm run test-e2e
```

Comment: I was using `mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:bionic` image which worked for me but this was giving me the idea, thanks!

Comment: I'm having the missing dependencies message despite using the docker image matching my playwright version

Comment: @OliCrt try a script with this:    - yarn playwright install --with-deps